# Error executing r.drain

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, rgrass7

I´m trying to do a Least Cost Path with Grass and when I try to use r.drain I can't. It say to me error raster map not found.

Comment: Well, do you have a raster map? Did you point your tool to it correctly? Are there any special signs in path or filename of this map?

Comment: Yes, I have a raster map and the filename is normal...

Comment: Please attach the complete error message as well as the protocol part to your question.

Comment: Did you set the computational region to the input raster at the beginning? i.e. `g.region rast=direccion_movi_80`. And are you sure that your point map punt80 has points in the region of direccion_movi_80 ?